# No module named 'selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Hi I have installed selenium but when i run the code irun into this error

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\flasshscore\main.py", line 1, in 
from selenium import webdriver
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium''

Comment: What command did you use to do the installation? AND what python version are you using?

Comment: What are your configurations in PyCharm, are you using as a interpreter the native Python from your system or a virtual environment?

Comment: Troubleshooting your `sys.path` is a very common FAQ; please search before asking, and then if you do ask, see the existing questions for what information to include. See also the [help] and in particular [How to ask.](/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

When ModuleNotFoundError occurs, I think the following steps are necessary:

1. Check if the module name was typped right;
2. Check if the module is installed in **current environment**;(some packages can't be installed just using "install + packagename", so make sure u have installed the package using right command)
3. Uninstall and reinstall;

As to ur problem, the most possible reason is that u are in a wrong environment. So please check if u correctly set the interpreter in Pycharm.